Working with yield and except in dependency; RuntimeError: generator didn't stop
I have some code on FastAPI 0.109.2 that I need to upgrade to 0.115.4. But when I do that I get an error that says: RuntimeError: generator didn't stop. I am pretty new to FastAPI; so, I was having a hard time finding a solution for this.
my endpoint looks something like this:
@router.get('/{activity_id}')
async def get_activity_detail(param_1: int,
                              response: Response,
                              creds: Creds = Depends(),
                              db:SQLServer = Depends(get_db):

# Does something

My get_db function looks like this:
def get_db() -> Generator:  # coverage: omit
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error : raised from {inspect.stack()[0][3]} - {str(e)}')
        raise
    finally:
        db.close()
        print(f'Closing the database connection')

Stack trace:
[2024-10-30 00:28:47 +0000] [25] [ERROR] Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 406, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 60, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 1054, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 113, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 187, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 165, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 62, in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 62, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 51, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 715, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 735, in app
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 288, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 76, in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 62, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 51, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 73, in app
    response = await f(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 290, in app
    async with AsyncExitStack() as async_exit_stack:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 745, in __aexit__
    raise exc_details[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 728, in __aexit__
    cb_suppress = await cb(*exc_details)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 217, in __aexit__
    await anext(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/concurrency.py", line 37, in contextmanager_in_threadpool
    await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 56, in run_sync
    return await get_async_backend().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 2441, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 943, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 149, in __exit__
    raise RuntimeError("generator didn't stop")
RuntimeError: generator didn't stop

Would really appreciate some help. Thanks! :)
I was not expecting to get any errors. I tried to follow the official documentation: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/dependencies-with-yield/. But being new to FastAPI, I am having some hard time finding a solution.

Please post the full traceback of the RuntimeError and any other of your code that is mentioned in the stack trace.

Updated the description with stack trace
